# Realm using xCode 8 & Swift 2.3 Failing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, realm

I recently updated to xCode 8 and I am choosing to stay with Swift 2.3

I am using Cocoapods to integrate Realm and it was working prior to the upgrade to xCode 8.

I searched around on Realm's GitHub and tried some solutions to no success.
In my podfile I have the following lines for Realm

```
pod 'Realm', git: 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', branch: 'master', submodules: true
pod 'RealmSwift', git: 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', branch: 'master', submodules: true

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
    end
  end
end
```

It installs successfully completes with message:

> Using Realm (1.1.0) Using RealmSwift (1.1.0)

When I relaunch my application:

- 68 warnings of missing files `RLM*` Files
- Error - `Umbrella header 'Realm.h not found`
- Error - `Cound not build Objective-C module Realm`

Comment: Have you tried using a bridging header?

Comment: @cloudcal no, how would you recommend using it? I did not have to use a bridging header in the past.

Comment: header isn't needed for Realm

Comment: @Alan Did you make sure that the User Legacy Swift Language version is set to 'YES' under the Pods? Might cause your issue if it's unspecified.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the exact same issue, and solved it my putting my 'User Legacy Swift Language version' to 'YES' for that Pod. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same problem. My Podfile looks similar to yours but I have this edit:

```
pod 'Realm', git: 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', branch: 'master', submodules: true
pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 2.3.0'

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
   end
  end
end
```

[As of v2.4.0, Swift 2.x is no longer supported.](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3916) Realm 2.3.0 is the last stable version that supports Swift 2.3. Also as Soundshock says ensure you have 'User Legacy Swift Language version' to 'YES' for RealmSwift Pod Target. Hope this helps.